# Acceptance test design in Requirements Validation (Software Engineering)

Tags: validation, acceptance-testing, requirements, requirements-management

Is **acceptance test** can be consider under requirements validation? Can you suggest me a good book for requirements validation that is freely available?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry, asking for book and other similar recommendations is off-topic for StackOverflow

Comment: see the guidelines of Stack overflow what questions can be asked..